# getline() function bunches the headings together

Tags: c++, header, getline, csv

The first row of my data file is the headers for the three (or four) columns of data:

```
%b02_a08    b02_a08_counts  b02_a08_eu
```

As you can see, the columns are TAB delimited. When I use `getline()`, it mashes the whole line together. If I use `getline(,,'\t')`, it returns `%b02_a08` for the line. I need the line separated out, because I read each header.

If anyone knows of a way to read the headers from a data file and put them into a `vector<string>` so that I can run Regex on them to find the one with "eu" in it, that is all I need to do. Well, that and read the columns of data, which I will probably run into the same TAB delimited problem, there.

Comment: (Guessed the language was `C++` from the vector reference. Please don't forget to add a language tag next time, and correct this one if I got it wrong.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the stream Luke...

as in,

```
// process the header
std::getline(some_input_stream, line))
{
  std::istringstream str(line);
  // Now reaad each field
  str >> header_1 >> header_2 >> header_3;
  if (str >> header_4)
  {
    // process the optional column
    have_col_4 = true;
  }
}

// Now to read the rows
while(some_input_stream >> col_1 >> col_2 >> col_3)
{
  if (have_col_4)
    some_input_stream >> col_4;
}
```

The last block can be done with `std::getline` too (i.e. read a line, construct a stream, then read from the stream), however this tends to be somewhat slower...

Comment: How would I use push_back() to put str (or "liness", which is what I have) to put the headers into a vector<string>?:

'getline(datFile, line);

istringstream liness(line);

liness >> 

while(!liness.end)
{
 getline(liness, temp, '\t');

 header.push_back(temp);
}'

Comment: You can use the funky `copy` line from @dasblinkenlight's answer.. or alternatively a simple while loop (`while(liness >> header_item) { vec.push_back(header_item); }` - remember that the stream will use whitespace as separator for strings)

Comment: header_item is a string that I need to declare?